# Prove that $\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta}_{LS},\hat{\beta}_{GLS})=\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}_{GLS})$ for linear model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, variance, least-squares, covariance, generalized-least-squares

I have a problem which is as follows:

> Given the linear model $y=X\beta+\epsilon$ and $\text{Var}(y)=\Sigma$, show that:
>   $$\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta}_{LS},\hat{\beta}_{GLS})=\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}_{GLS})$$
>   and compute also $\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta}_{GLS},\hat{\beta}_{GLS}-\hat{\beta}_{LS})$.

I'm so lost I do not know where to begin.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Start with the formulas for the variances and covariances.

Comment: Ok, I got the $\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}_{GLS})$, but when computing $\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta}_{LS},\hat{\beta}_{GLS})=E[\hat{\beta}_{LS}\cdot\hat{\beta}_{GLS}]-E[\hat{\beta}_{LS}]E[\hat{\beta}_{GLS}]$ I got stuck in the first expected value, I got the right-hand side of the equality. I do not manage to get the expectance in a form like $E(Ay)=A\mu$ or $E(y'Ay)=tr(AV)+\mu'A\mu$. Any ideas?

Comment: Since OLS is just GLS with a unit variance matrix, you automatically have $\operatorname{Var}(\hat \beta_{LS})$.  Even better, you can probably compute $\operatorname{Var}(\hat \beta_{LS} - \hat\beta_{GLS})$.  Once you have those, it's easy to solve for the covariance.